# What is the most efficient way to select a fallback element if original element is not present in DOM with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, performance

In a jQuery Plugin I am writing, I want to check for specific elements inside the DOM object the plugin is called on. The code looks kind of like this:

```
//the object that you call the plugin on, stored in the variable "o"
o = this;

//Store children of a child element inside "o" in the variable "elInsideO"
elInsideO = o.find('selector').children('childrenSelector');

/* check if elInsideO is empty in case 'selector' is not present and then look for 
alternative element 'selector2' */
if (elInsideO.length == 0) {
    elInsideO = o.find('selector2').children('childrenSelector');
}
```

Is there a more efficent way to make this selection? One more possibility I can think of is this:

```
if (o.find('selector').length != 0) {
    elInsideO = o.find('selector').children('childrenSelector');
} else {
    elInsideO = o.find('selector2').children('childrenSelector');
}
```

Which one of these solutions is more efficient (meaning performs better)? Is there another way that is even better?

Thx for any help!

Comment: I'd change the second method and store the result from `selector` in a variable: `var tmp;if ((tmp=o.find('selector')).length != 0) { elInsideO=tmp.children('childrenSelector'); ......`

Comment: What's wrong with the existing code? it's just fine.

Comment: @ gdoron: Nothing is wrong with it, I'm just always looking for "the best way" to accomplish things :)

Comment: @RobW: I kind of like that approach, allthough I would not know how to continue that code for tmp needs to be changed in case it would be empty. It seems that part of the task would be more complicated this way. But I think checking first for the parent element and store the result in a variable and afterwards checking for the children might be the least redundant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finaly made some benchmarking tests for the first time. I used jsPerf. According to the test the least efficient way is this:

```
elInsideO = o.find('selector').children('childrenSelector');
if (elInsideO.length == 0) {
    elInsideO = o.find('selector2').children('childrenSelector');
}
```

I tested three more variants that give me the same result:

2:

```
if (o.find('selector').length != 0) {
    elInsideO = o.find('selector').children('childrenSelector');
} else {
    elInsideO = o.find('selector2').children('childrenSelector');
}
```

3:

```
 if (o.find('selector').length != 0) {
    elParent = o.find('selector');
 } else {
    elParent = o.find('selector2');
 }
 elInsideO = stopsParent.children('childrenSelector');
```

4:

```
elParent = o.find('selector');
if (elParent.length == 0) {
    elParent = o.find('selector2');
}
elInsideO = elParent.children('childrenSelector');
```

2, 3 and 4 all perform better than the first variant. Although the test always declares another one of those three as the best, so you can't tell for sure which one of them is best, the first one always performs worst. 
I prefer the fourth variant, because it stores the parent element in a extra variable, so I can use it for other purposes as well and i have one less line of code compared to variant 3.

You can test for yourself here:

http://jsperf.com/fallback-selection

Comment: I think the main thing you can take away from that is that with 20,000 ops per sec you don't actually need to worry about the speed, just do it in the way you find most readable. :)

Comment: Ok, good point, but still I like to do things most optimal. As you usually can accomplish one and the same thing in different ways when coding, going for performance helps alot deciding which way to take. Even if like in this case the impact on the overall performance is marginal (and still I had to decide on three equaly performing options).

Comment: My point was that if things are equal in performance then make the code the easiest to understand that you can. Maintainability should also be high in your mind as a second place to performance. Also "premature optimisation" can actually be more of a time sink than is good. If you spend a couple of hours optimising something that is running fast enough already then that's a couple of hours you could have spent on something that needed it more. There is of course academic benefit to optimisation but there is a trade off.

Comment: Agreed. I have to admit this question resulted from my curiosity, not from a real performance optimization need. So eventualy I would have left the code as is anyway, but still – I wanted to know :)

Answer (score 1):

Those two code fragments do something different... if `o.find('selector')` has elements but those elements have no children the first method will go to the second selector. The second bit of code however will return the empty set of non-existant children. So in this case the qeustion isn't of which performs better but which is correct. :)

In the circumstance where you are guaranteed children then I would have thought they would be much the same assumign you cached the results of `o.find('selector')` in a variable rather than running it in the conditional check and again in the results. In both cases you are doing `o.find('selector')` first. In both cases if it exists then you get the children so the time will be much the same.

If it doesn't exist then the first method will call children too but calling this on an empty jquery object is goign to be trivial amounts of time. They then both proceed to do the same thing.

The second set of code avoids some redundant calling but otherwise you are goign to notice negligible differences.

As always if you believe this performance is truly critical then perform some benchmarking to test for yourself which performs best in the situations you are using it.

Comment: You are right, those code fragments do different things. The case is that those children are guaranteed to be there but the parent of the children can be of two different kinds. Maybe I should have asked for the most elegant and least redundant way (assuming it would automaticaly be the most efficient).